# Adding iterated array values to xlwt sheet

Tags: python, arrays, excel, for-loop, xlwt

For every 4 values in this array, I want it to write to a new row in the spreadsheet while disregarding the first column. This is because I'm going to be putting different values from a separate array there.

For example, I have five columns:

```
A B C D E
```

However A is off limits...

I have an array of numbers 1-12 and I want to write them like so:

```
A B C D E
  1 2 3 4
  5 6 7 8
  9 10 11 12
```

The numbers wont actually be in sequential order in my real code thus why some form of iteration will probably have to be used here rather logic that depends on the specific value.

I got close with something like this in my test code, but the values after 8 start to get screwy, I'm assuming it's referring to 4 as a member of the array rather than a length condition...

```
s1 = wb.add_sheet("Test")

s1.write(0, 0, "Col 1")
s1.write(0, 1, "Col 2")
s1.write(0, 2, "Col 3")
s1.write(0, 3, "Col 4")
s1.write(0, 4, "Col 5")

test_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
list2 = []
for val in test_list:
list2.append(str(val))

for c, col_val in enumerate(list2):
    for r, row_val in enumerate(col_val):
        if c + 1 > 4:
            s1.write(r + 1 + 1, c - 4 + 1, row_val)
        if c + 1 <= 4:
            s1.write(1, 1 + c, row_val)
```

If anyone has a good way of achieving this, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this I took 2 generators. One generator gives me the next column I should write at and the other generator that gives me the next row I should write at. Generators might sound intimidating but over here they really simplify the problem you are facing (with the advantage of having a slightly lower memory footprint).

**Key Idea**

(Example for 5 columns)

- Column number you are writing to follows the sequence 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4..
- Row number you are writing to follows the sequence 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,...

So you see the pattern? Both column and row are independently sequences which can be obtained using generators or simple loops. (That will take more memory though)

**Working code**

```
s1 = wb.add_sheet("Test")

s1.write(0, 0, "Col 1")
s1.write(0, 1, "Col 2")
s1.write(0, 2, "Col 3")
s1.write(0, 3, "Col 4")
s1.write(0, 4, "Col 5")

test_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
list2 = []
for val in test_list:
    list2.append(str(val))

# Generator for column
def next_c_index():
    c = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    while True:
        for i in c:
            yield i

# Generator for row
def next_r_index(ncolumns=5):
    """
    Assumes you start from writing from 2nd row.
    :ncolumns = number of columns (default 5)
    Eg. 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2
    """
    n = 0
    r = 0
    while True:
        # In every cycle of 4
        if (n)%(ncolumns-1)==0:
            r += 1
        n += 1
        yield r

# Since you have 5 columns I pass 5 while calling row generator
row = next_r_index(ncolumns=5)
col = next_c_index()
for val in list2:
    s1.write(row.next(), col.next(), val)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. I was thinking of trying to create some kind function that broke this down further rather than my desperate fight with the for loops. I'll have to do some more reading on Generators.

Comment: @chrisl0lz: Using the sequence key ideas I mentioned above you can do the same with for loops also. Generators just make it cool because we don't have to define fixed size sequences and then think where to stop iterating, etc. :)